# How to lookup a date and return the lowest item in a row

Tags: excel, formula

I have two worksheets.  On Sheet1, column A is a date/time, column B is a float number, and column C is where I will put this formula. Sheet1 (example 2 columns): `6/1/2020 3:48   1.1117`

Sheet2 has a date/time in column A sorted ascending and float values in columns B:DA.  Sheet2 (example 7 columns): `06/01/2020 00:24    1.1103  1.1100  1.1096  1.1103  1.1114  1.1107`

My formula criteria is:

- Find the same date/time from Sheet1!A2 in Sheet2!A:A
- Find all values in that row found in criteria 1 that are greater than Sheet1!L2
- Return the lowest value found

I thought I could do: `Min(Filter(Sheet2!A2:DA5,("="A2)*(">"L2),1))`.  But that did not work.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this formula. It will work in Excel versions 2016 and up. For earlier versions you will need an array formula using MIN and IF separately. Look for [guidance here](https://www.get-digital-help.com/excel-find-the-smallest-value-in-a-list-but-bigger-than-10/).

```
[C2] =MINIFS(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$G$8,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0),0),INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$G$8,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0),0),">"&$B2)
```

`INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$G$8,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0),0)` specifies the row determined by the Match function. It's a sheet row. Therefore the data range must start in row 1. G8 is the last cell with data in my test range. You would do well to define *Sheet2!$B$1:$G$8* as a named range.

The formula simply asks for the lowest value from that range to be returned which is larger than B2. The MINIFS function is designed to work with different columns but you only need one. That's why the range is repeated twice, once to draw the minimum from and once to contain the criteria.

Comment: Exact match may not work as he has different time with date in same cell.

Comment: How would that impact it?  I want the date and time to be an exact match.  Plus, it is an underlining number (date/time is just a custom format), so we want an exact match of that number (i.e. its matching 43983.16 in this case).  Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Thank you!  It works perfectly. I appreciate the help!

Comment: How would I modify this if the columns of the Min_Range are not adjacent?  meaning, instead of it being B1:G8, it is B1:C1 & F1:G1?

Comment: I just follow your suggestion and Define a Name that has the appropriate columns.  That will work?  I tried it, and I don't think it is working, so must be a better way

Comment: I think you will have to draw the value from each of the ranges separately into a MIN() function, using the above formula, which then gives you the lower of the two results.

Comment: All ranges are always addressed using names. "Sheet1!A1:C14" is a generic name created using coordinates and "MyData" is a given name assigned by the user. Whatever works with  one name also works with another. If your experience is different that has to do with the way you assigned the name. Use a simpler formula like `=SUM(MyData)` to test your ranges. I also use VBA `Debug.Print  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range.Address` which is especially useful for dynamic ranges whose address you can't look up in the Names Manager.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `Debug.Print  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MyData").Address`

Comment: @Variatus, I think you are right.  I did just break them out seperately, as my data just requires to be calculated, not to be done in the best way.  Thank you!